# Joining all address details to customer collection

Tags: magento, collections

I'm looking to join all customer address attributes onto the full customer collection.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->joinField('is_active', 'customer/address', 'is_active','parent_id=entity_id');
```

gives me the fatal error:

```
Mage_Core_Exception: Can't retrieve entity config: customer/address in /app/Mage.php on line 563
```

As I'm using Enterprise, we have the ability to add customer address attributes, so using the method of joining specific address attributes is not satisfactory like in this code snippet:

```
$collection->addNameToSelect()
    ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find a way, although it's not super elegant but it works for me. Basically, we can cycle through all of the address attributes and add our `joinAttribute()`s that way.

```
$addressCollection = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$addressCollection->getSelect()->limit(1);
$address = $addressCollection->getFirstItem();
foreach ($address->getAttributes() as $attribute) {
    if (is_null($attribute->getAttributeID()) || is_null($attribute->getFrontendLabel()) || ($attribute->getFrontendLabel() == '')) {
        continue;
    }
    $collection->joinAttribute($attribute->getName(), 'customer_address/' . $attribute->getName(), 'default_billing', null, 'left');
}
```

Note that we ignoring attributes without labels as I only want "real" customer address information.